# fieldsets don't work with django constance

Tags: python, django, settings

I am using `django constance` with `database` and set it up according to this [documentation](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

And so far it works fine, except for the Fieldsets-Option. I am using exactly the code from the tutorial [here](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fieldsets):

```
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'SITE_NAME': ('My Title', 'Website title'),
    'SITE_DESCRIPTION': ('', 'Website description'),
    'THEME': ('light-blue', 'Website theme'),
}

CONSTANCE_CONFIG_FIELDSETS = {
    'General Options': ('SITE_NAME', 'SITE_DESCRIPTION'),
    'Theme Options': ('THEME',),
}
```

However, I am getting this 
[image]

So what's missing is the two lines "Generel Options" and "Theme Options". Do I have to customize something in the settings first? I don't think I missed anything from the tutorial here.

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of django-constance are you using?

Comment: the version is `django-constance==1.3.4` and additionally, I install `django-constance[database]`

Comment: Did you have any lucky? :'(

Comment: Well, it always happens to me that after ask something, I found my solution. In my case we had a custom template for the constance web, so I had to update the html code with the new version (also we were using a very old version of constance)